# Vue getter property undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuex, getter

i have state **pages** obtained from api

```
const state = () => ({
  info: [],
  pages: []
})
```

and **Getter**

```
const getters = {
  // HomePage_Getters
  HomeAdvantages(state) {
    return state.pages.find((page) => (page.template = 'home')).home_advantages
  }
}
```

On the vue Page

```
        <div>
          {{ HomeAdvantages }}
        </div>
...
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({ HomeAdvantages: 'modules/general/HomeAdvantages' })
  },
```

On Page refresh i get

> Cannot read property 'home_advantages' of undefined

But in the state **pages** property is present

How i could solve this?

I will be grateful, for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pages` property is empty, then `state.pages.find((page) => (page.template = 'home'))` may return `undefined`.
And in your code you want to get `home_advantages` from the `find` result.
Your code should look like this:

```
var page = state.pages.find((page) => (page.template == 'home'));
if (!page) {
   return null;
}
return page.home_advantages
```